# sniff wireless digital thermometer data

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have bought a weber wireless digital thermometer (http://store.weber.com/accessories/category/cook/1552) and I want to sniff the data between base-station and handheld.
I have already tried to get some technical infos for that model, but i didn't find someting :-(

Do you think I could achieve this with a raspberry pi?
How can i find out its radio-frequency? 433mhz?
What would you recommend as a starting-point?